# Discrod.py rewrite @bot.command not responding no matter what i do

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

ok, first time ever asking a question so i apologize if i do something wrong. i am trying to use the @bot.command feature and it wont return anything no matter what i do.

```
    from discord.ext import commands
    from config import *
    from discord import *
    import discord
    import time
    import random
```

```
client = discord.Client()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+')

@bot.command()
async def yes(ctx):
    await ctx.send('yes')
    print("worked")

bot.add_command(yes)

client.run("token")
bot.run("token")
```

so in theory when someone types "+yes" is discord it should respond with "yes" as well as print "worked" in the terminal. instead i just get nothing. i know the bot works because i have '''other on_message''' commands but i have to use the offical '''@bot.command''' for this because it will eventually be part of interactivity.

Comment: Did you add the `bot.process_command(message)` function at the end of every `on_message` event?

Comment: don’t run the client, you’re not using it anywhere, run only the bot

Answer (score -1):

You need to supply the command to the command, That's how I usually do it. Unsure of your method but perhaps try it this way:

```
client = discord.Client()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+')

@bot.command(name="yes")
async def yes(ctx):
    await ctx.send('yes')
    print("worked")

# bot.add_command(yes) # How will it know to map function yes to the command yes?

client.run("token")
bot.run("token)
```

Comment: so i added that but then it gives me this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hunte\Desktop\Discord bot\Bot\DiscordBot\DiscordBot0.3.py", line 91, in <module>
    bot.add_command(yes)
  File "C:\Users\hunte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1137, in add_command
    raise TypeError('The command passed must be a subclass of Command')
TypeError: The command passed must be a subclass of Command

Comment: @HunterTheSoundGuy looks like there has been some changes to how discord rewritten works, once more. Join their discord and the auto bot will reply to you.